# Node.js debug package not working with .env file

Tags: node.js, debugging, environment-variables

I want to use the debug package to log messages like this:

```
const debug = require('debug')('app:Debug');
debug('this is a log message!');
```

Then in `package.json`:

```
"scripts": {
    "dev": "DEBUG=* nodemon server"
}
```

And it worked perfectly.

Now I want to store all my environment variables in the `.env` file like so:

```
PORT=5000
NODE_ENV=development
DEBUG=*
```

And if I do this:

```
const debug = require('debug')('app:Debug');
const dotenv = require('dotenv');
dotenv.config();
debug('this is a log message!');
```

No message is logged. I checked the `DEBUG` environment variable with `console.log('process.env.DEBUG')` and it is set. I don't understand where the problem is.

Any help will be appreciated thanks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Nevermind guys. I removed the `node_modules` directory and re-installed the packages and everything works fine.

Answer (score 3):

You probably need to init `dotenv` before you setup the `debug`-module:

```
const dotenv = require('dotenv');
dotenv.config();
const debug = require('debug')('app:Debug');
debug('this is a log message!');
```

Comment: Can't reproduce this :/ Are you sure the `.env` file is in the root directory of your project? Alternatively you can specify the path explicitly: `dotenv.config({ path: __dirname+ '/path-to.env' });`

Comment: Yes. The `.env` file is in the root directory and all the environment variables are set. I checked with a `console.log()`